# Como inverter a ordem de uma String em Dart?

Tags: string, método, dart

Eu sei que em outras linguagens têm métodos para obter o inverso de uma `String` e já procurei em Dart, mas não estou encontrando nada.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
String inverter(String v) {
   String inverso ='';
   for (int i = v.length; i >= 1; i--) {
     inverso += v.substring(i-1, i);
   }
   return inverso;
}
```

mas é complicado ter isso no código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já que está procurando uma forma pronta (não é a forma mais eficiente):

```
void main() {
    print("teste".split('').reversed.join());
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/tcRfO2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Reverse). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Dart/Reverse.dt).

Só não entendi o que é complicado ter no código.

Comment: era isso que estava procurando, obrigado pela ajuda, e quanto ao 'complicado', é que eu tinha que ter esse trecho no meu código e eu sabia que deveria ter algo pronto para isso como você mostrou.